# Hit a deer and piece to headlight snapped

Tags: car, headlight, mitsubishi

Okay so I hit a deer. There’s actually not too much damage except for some dents and this plastic part that snapped. The headlight moves Around now so I know I have to replace it but I don’t know what part it is. It’s a Mitsubishi Mirage 2017. The deer ran into my passenger side.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will almost certainly find that that broken piece is an integral molded part of the headlamp body.

Which sadly means you will need to purchase the complete unit.

You might attempt a repair but it will need to be strong.

Comment: Loctite 406 seems to be a good candidate

Comment: I've had some success fixing plastic parts using fiberglass repair tape and epoxy, the fiberglass tape bridges gaps and adds rigidity once the epoxy cures. However, in this case even I'd just replace the part, there's just too much damage. Plus you it may no longer be watertight.

Comment: @GdD correct, just gluing the broken piece never works.

Comment: True @Moab, there's not a glue in existence which can hold snapped plastic together edge to edge with any strength. There are heat welding techniques, not something I've ever tried